# Why don't more people fill out the "about me" section?

Tags: discussion, users

Just wondering where people acquire their knowledge

Answer (score 9):

I was thinking of filling out my profile to read "Doctorate in Aeronautics, MIT, 1999.  40,000+ hours 747 & 787.  I trained Chuck Yeager and without me the B-2 wouldn't even be kind of stealthy."  But I worry that people might not believe me :D.

Kidding aside, I've often wished that people would identify themselves on this site on several occasions.  But, well, it's not really what the site is about (and there's no way to verify that what is said in a profile is true anyway...).

Stack Exchange is about mass voting, not a particular expert.  Heck, if the right answer comes from a complete idiot, who cares?  If the answer is correct the community will vote it up, and the truth should shine through (in theory, I recognize this idea is not without its problems.  But it's the idea SE is going with.)

I will say this though, we do have a chat room, and if you do want to get to know some of the pilots who answer questions on the stack, you might try poking your head in there on occasion :).

Answer (score 7):

A shiny fake internet badge is clearly not sufficient motivation.
We should begin offering real badgers in the future.

---

Note: as far as I'm aware stack has no plans to ship badgers.
If badgers are shipped I request that mine be of the "honey" variety.

Comment: That would be "[The Crazy Nastyass Honey Badger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg)" variety I assume? :-)

Comment: @DeltaLima I will also settle for a [crafty cage-escaping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c36UNSoJenI) variant.

Comment: Now I want one too!

Comment: Nobody wants the good old version [on drugs](http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/flash/badgers)?

Comment: Badger badger badger badger badger ...

Comment: Mushroom Mushroom!

Answer (score 5):

I have filled out my 'about me' and claimed my Autobiographer badge.  I just didn't put any actual text in there.

SE isn't a social network; it's not really about the people.  If the credentials of a poster are relevant to an answer (e.g., when relying on one's personal experience as a source), they should be stated in that answer.

Comment: +1 for "SE isn't a social network". I signed up here after leaving another science-oriented forum whose organizer(s) seemed to be intent on turning it into one.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is just pure laziness. I have no license to display but i like airplane a lot. So reading this site daily gives me peace of mind and no need to fill about me section

---

Answer (score 1):

Why do I have to fill out my “about me” section?

Comment: You don't have to, it's completely optional

Comment: @Pondlife that is exactly the opposite of the assumption behind the question (and the point of this answer)

Comment: @Federico Wasn't my intention to make that assumption but I see that it does. Ppl shouldn't feel pressure to enter info if they choose not to. Was intended much more tongue-in-cheek than it came across. I flagged it this morning for deletion as it is inappropriate. I don't think I can delete it myself. My apologies.

Comment: @TomMcW if you realize that your intention is not understood I encourage you to edit your question to make your point of view clearer, not to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ashamed to admit how inexperienced a pilot I am compared to others here, so I just put a picture of me flying and let you figure out the rest...

Comment: He he he! Got more'n me! Closest I've ever gotten is a jumpseat and about an hour riding with a friend in his single engine Mooney.